# NodeJS app can't find Sequelize if launched from the wrong path

Tags: linux, node.js, sequelize.js

If I go to mydir/core and enter

```
/usr/bin/node app.js &
```

my application starts fine.  But if I go to mydir and  enter

```
/usr/bin/node core/app.js &
```

I get errors.

```
    core/user/dbConfig.js:6
var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.connections.postgres.database, config.con
                                                ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'postgres' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dwil/code15/git_code/YB/root/services/core/user/dbConfig.js:6:49)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dwil/code15/git_code/YB/root/services/core/app.js:12:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
```

sudo npm install -g sequelize doesn't solve it.

How do I install / configure so that I can start from a different directory?  This matters b/c I'm trying to start it via Monit.  That's why "just change into the right directory" is not a viable answer.  Thanks!

Comment: check your `config.connections` is loaded properly.

Comment: How do I check that, @Kamrul?

Comment: just try either by printing using (`console.log(config, config.connections)`) or debugging (there are options for debug).

Comment: I added the console.log line right above the one that was breaking.  When I launch from the directory in which it works, I do get extra information logged.  When I launch from another directory, I get nothing logged.  Only the error occurs.  As if ... it's a compile errors preventing the logging from running.  but I'm not sure that makes any sense w/ JS.

Comment: nothing logged means that your `config` is empty or `undefined`. Please check the relative path which loading the `config` object.

Comment: Thanks, Kamrul.  You've set me on the right path.